# Posicionar elementos dentro de una celda (td) de una tabla HTML

Tags: html, css

Actualmente tengo una columna de una tabla de datos, donde se muestra un número al lado derecho y un icono al lado izquierdo dentro de la misma celda.

Sin embargo, me gustaría se mostrará en sentido contrario (número a la izquierda, icono a la derecha) como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: actual vs deseado]

A continuación muestro un fragmento del código:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="float: left;">
      42
    </div>      
    <div style="float: right;">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
        error_outline
      </i>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="float: left;">
        -326
      </div>      
    <div style="float: right;">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
        error_outline
      </i>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="float: left;">
       127
      </div>      
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

La idea no es crear otra columna adicional para ubicar el icono, sino dentro de la misma celda posicionar el icono y el número para dar la sensación de que estaban divididos por una línea y el número alineado a la derecha.

Intenté cambiar el orden y el float y se muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el 42 no se muestra como espero porque quiero que todos los números se encuentren alineados a la derecha.

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: solo debes cambiar el orden y el float

Comment: ya lo intenté, sin embargo no se muestra como espero, Porque quiero que los números estén alineados a la derecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta reemplazar el *Float* por el **Display** en los **DIV** y las **TD** las alineas a la derecha de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    42
                </div>      
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
                        error_outline
                    </i>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    -326
                </div>      
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
                        error_outline
                    </i>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
               <div style="display: inline-block;">
                  127
               </div>      
               <div style="display: inline-block; width:16px;">
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr> 
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como puedo hacer mantener los números alineados en el caso donde no haya iconos? Por ejemplo el 127 de la imagen.

Comment: Puedes agregar al DIV en dónde no habrá icono el ancho que ocuparía el mismo. Edite mi respuesta para incluir el caso del 127 que mencionas. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien, lo que buscas es únicamente cambiar el orden del ícono y el número en cada celda..
En este caso únicamente será necesario alternar su orden en el HTML:

```html
<td>
  <div style="float: left;">
    42
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <i class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
      error_outline
    </i>
  </div>
</td>
```

**Edit:**

Ahora entiendo tu pregunta.. Hay varias maneras de hacer esto, pero se me ocurre:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px; text-align:right;">
        42
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
          error_outline
        </i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;">
        -326
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
          error_outline
        </i>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fíjate que hice varios cambios para lograr el estilo que entendí que necesitabas, además de agregar `<table>` y `<tr>`.

Comment: De esta forma lo intenté pero quiero que los números queden alineados. Ya edite mi pregunta para aclarar mi idea.

Answer (score 1):

Una cosa que puedes hacer es darle un ancho al `div` que tiene los números y alinear el contenido a la derecha con `text-align`.Puedes ajustar los valores a tu gusto, yo le he dado un 70% de ancho para los números y para asegurarme que el `div` del icono ocupa el resto del espacio también le he dado un ancho del 30%:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="float: left; width:70%; text-align:right;">
          42
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width:30%">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
        error_outline
      </i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="float: left; width:70%; text-align:right;">
          -326
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;width:30%;">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 82, 82); caret-color: rgb(255, 82, 82);">
        error_outline
      </i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="float: left; width:70%; text-align:right;">
          -326
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Por otra parte sería mejor que sacaras los estilos a un archivo `.css` aparte en lugar de ponerlos todos en el html.